# How to remove error records from a Dynamic dataframe in AWS glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a dynamic dataframe which contains error records.Please find the code below.

```
val rawDataFrame = glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = rawDBName, tableName = rawTBLName).getDynamicFrame();
    println(s"RAW_DF-----count: ${rawDataFrame.count} errors: ${rawDataFrame.errorsCount}")
```

The above print statement prints as below.

```
RAW_DF-----count: 168456 errors: 4
```

I need to create a dynamic data frame which contains only 168456 records and I need to eliminate 4 error records.Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error records are not converting to Spark's DataFrame so try to transform your DynamicFrame to df and back:

```
val noErrorsDyf = DynamicFrame(rawDataFrame.toDF(), glueContext)
```

Comment: Thank You Yuriy... It really helped me a lot.